# How to show custom size option editable in dropdown in customer wishlist page?

Tags: magento2, custom, wishlist

I want show custom size option editable in dropdown in customer wishlist page
[image]

Comment: Can you specify into details.

Comment: i want to make this size custom option attribute edit able on this wishlist page like product page